# Mirror the entire official NuGet repository

Tags: nuget, mirror

Setting up a build server in an air gapped environment (no internet connection).

There are [tools](https://github.com/emgarten/NuGet.CatalogReader) for mirroring but I'm wondering if there are any licensing issues mirroring the entire NuGet repository (https://api.nuget.org).

Also, does anyone know the size of the entire repo?

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak to the legality of mirroring the NuGet repository.

I used `NuGet.CatalogReader` to get information on every package in the repository.  I then made a `HEAD` request for the `.nupkg` URL to determine the `Content-Length`. I summed the size of each package and came up with ~2.36 TB.  This should give you a good ballpark figure.